# Why the user won’t see the intermediate state after call setState() immediately in componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React Docs, https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidMount(). It will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser updates the screen. This guarantees that even though the render() will be called twice in this case, the user won’t see the intermediate state. Use this pattern with caution because it often causes performance issues. In most cases, you should be able to assign the initial state in the constructor() instead. It can, however, be necessary for cases like modals and tooltips when you need to measure a DOM node before rendering something that depends on its size or position.

In my own opinion, when we call componentDidMount() the component has rendered once. The we call  setState, the component will render again. How can I understand `It will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser updates the screen.`? Doesn't the first render() update the screen?

Comment: Given JS' userland is single threaded, if you modify DOM twice during event loop iteration - the layout will be painted only once. In other words: `e.textContent = 'foo'; e.textContent = 'bar';` is 1 paint. not 2.

Answer (score 1):

> Doesn't the first `render()` update the screen?

No. On the "Render phase", which the `render()` call is part of it, you make changes to the Virtual DOM.

So such phase doesn't update the screen.

> How can I understand "it will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser updates the screen".

The `componentDidMount` lifecycle is part of the "Commit phase", which commits changes to the DOM, so as the note says, by calling React API, you can trigger another render, i.e trigger another "Render phase".

- [The Component Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)
- [Lifecycle diagram](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/)